# IAR Embedded Workbench error

Tags: embedded, wifi, iar

I have a question about IAR Embedded Workbench IDE.

I have WIFI module which is named MSP-EXP430FR5739.

I don't know this error.

Error is below:

> Fatal Error[e72]: Segment DATA20_Z must be defined in a segment definition option (-Z, -b or -P)

Error while running Linker

I want to solve this error.
Please help me.

[CC3000 Basic Wi-Fi example application for MSP430](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/CC3000_Basic_Wi-Fi_example_application_for_MSP430)

Answer (score 3):

Seems to be [an issue](http://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/msp430/f/166/p/179066/929884#929884) with the linker file. You need to make a copy of the IAR version of the linker file (a `.xcl` file) for the specific MSP430 chip you are using, place it in your project directory, and then edit it to contain the following line:

```
-Z(DATA)DATA20_I,DATA20_Z,DATA20_N,DATA20_HEAP+_DATA20_HEAP_SIZE
```

In the `// Read/write memory` group.

Some of the code you are using contains directives to be placed in that segment. But the compiler does not know about that segment because it has not been defined in the linker configuration file.